# Position GADBannerView on bottom of screen

Tags: ios, swift, admob

My `GADBannerView` is currently at the top, how can I change its position to the bottom?

```
var Banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)  
var request:GADRequest = GADRequest()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    func showBanner() {
        Banner.hidden = false
        Banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-**************"
        Banner.rootViewController = self
        Banner.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(Banner)
        Banner.loadRequest(request)            
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID];                
    }
}
```

What should I add?

Comment: `var Banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)` should be `banner`. Names starting with a capital letter are used for classes, not variables. Also, you should use `let` instead of `var`. For example, `let banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Banner.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,
                      y:self.view.frame.size.height - Banner.frame.size.height,
                      width:Banner.frame.size.width,
                      height:Banner.frame.size.height)
```